# How to draw a small part of a parabola far from bend point using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to draw just part of a `parabola` (far from bend point) and then making a star shape by joining four of them. All examples of `parabola`s that I have seen contains the bend point. I think a solution for drawing a small part of `parabola` is `clip` trick but I don't know how to rotate and join them locally.

Precisely I want to use the following area enclosed by four parabola, to `fill` or `clip` using it.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw(0,0)  parabola [parabola height =3cm](4,0) node[midway, above]{aaaa};
\draw[rotate={180}](2,-2) parabola [parabola height =3cm](6,-2);
\draw[rotate=90](0,0) parabola [parabola height =3cm](4,0) ;
\draw[rotate={-90}](-2,-2) parabola [parabola height =3cm](2,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Also I have problem with the position of `label` on middle of `parabola`. 
Here is what I want:
[image]

How to draw just colored region?

Comment: could atleast show us a figure of what you desire and what you have tried so-far?

Comment: You could use Bézier curves. There is also `\pgfpathquadraticcurveto` as a convenience wrapper to create quadratic Bézier curves (which internally are cubic, too). Ti*k*Z syntax would be to use `controls` with the correct control points.

Comment: Isn't the question clear enough?

Comment: @C.F.G: Draw a graphic on a napkin, add some descriptive arrows and notation to identify what you mean by "not the bend of a parabola", take a picture of it and upload it as part of your question. You really need to spoonfeed your audience if you want help in drawing something that requires some crystal ball gazing...

Comment: Ti*k*Z allows you to plot functions in any domain. Just try `\draw plot[smooth,variable=\x,domain=2:4] ({\x},{\x*\x});`.

Answer (score 1):

We can combine two parabolas each and only have two paths. Those we can feed to [PGFPlots' `fillbetween`](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/libs-fillbetween). The `backgrounds` library provides the  `background` layer so that we don't have to interact with the paths twice. (A solution that doesn't put the filling on a background layer – and thus possibly behind other stuff – is provided in the second diagram.)

The `ext.paths.timer` library of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext) provides a timer for the `parabola` path operation.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{ext.paths.timer, backgrounds, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[bend pos=.5, bend={+(0,3)}]
\draw [name path=A] {[rotate=90] (4,0) parabola (0,0)}
                                       parabola (4,0) node[above, midway]{aaaa};
\draw [name path=B, shift={(-2,2)}, rotate=180]
                    {[rotate=90] (4,0) parabola (0,0)}
                                       parabola (4,0);
\tikzfillbetween[
  of={A and B},
  split, every even segment/.style=path only,
  on layer=background] {yellow}
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz[bend pos=.5, bend={+(0,3)}]
\path (0,0) edge[name path global=A, to path={
   {[rotate=90] (4,0) parabola (0,0)}
                      parabola (4,0) node[above, midway]{aaaa}}] (0,0)
      (0,0) edge[shift={(-2,2)}, rotate=180, name path global=B, to path={
   {[rotate=90] (4,0) parabola (0,0)}
                      parabola (4,0)}] (0,0)
  [fill=yellow, intersection segments={of=A and B, sequence=L2 -- R2}];
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Maybe OP just wants to draw the border of the yellow region? Replace `\draw` with `\path[overlay]` and use `\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B, split, every even segment/.style={path only, overlay}]{path only, draw}`.